# how to create class like laravel to call class methodes consecutive

Tags: php, laravel, class

hello guys its question for me to how write some class like laravel .
i think this type of class more easy to use
code example :

```
ClassName::method1('value')->method2('value')->method3('value');
```

if you attention methodes are use Continuous

i seen this kind of class in in laravel on route part so i have interested in this class i want to yuse it in my own programs  !

is this way effective on loading  ?

i will be happy to help with a example
if you can explain it

thank you.

Comment: Look up "PHP Method Chaining" or "PHP Fluid Interface" on Google and read through some of the results there. The basics are that each method returns "itself", so you can chain them together, but there are plenty of tutorials on how to do this if you search for them hard enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example might help with the concept of method chaining.

Methods `one()`, `two()` and `three()` each set a property, before returning the current object, using `return $this`.

Returning `$this` (the object) allows the chaining of methods, as you can call another method on the returned object:

```
<?php
class Movie
{
    private string $one = '';
    private string $two = '';
    private string $three = '';

    public function one(): object
    {
        $this->one = "One ";
        return $this; // return object
    }

    public function two(): object
    {
        $this->two = "Flew Over the ";
        return $this; // return object
    }

    public function three(): object
    {
        $this->three = "Cuckoo's Nest";
        return $this; // return object
    }

    public function show(): string
    {
        return $this->one . $this->two . $this->three;
    }

}

$movie = new Movie();
echo $movie->one()->two()->three()->show();
```

See it in [action](https://3v4l.org/XUjde)